# facebook app - auto add tab when app gets installed

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, facebook

Is there a way to automatically add the tab of an application to the users profile page, after he installed the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you could, then everyone would do it and tabs would become useless. Especially since you can only have 3 tabs showing at any one time. You can create a button to make it easier for the user to add it as a tab.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:add-profile-tab